# RenderFlex overflowed by 388 pixels on the bottom and overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am learning flutter development and want to make a screen in which a container should be placed at bottom of screen and also the remaining screen have content which should be Scrollable.
here is the body of `Scaffold` widget

```
body:Stack(

        children: <Widget>[
      Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0  , 0.0 , 0.0 ),
      height: double.infinity,
          child:SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                 Container(
                   height: 100,
                   child: Text(description),
                 ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Text(description),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
      ) ,
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom:0,
            child:  new Container(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, 0.0, -20.0),
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Column(

                      children: <Widget>[


                        InkWell(
                          child:  Image.asset('assets/bt1.png'),
                          onTap: (){
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/help');
                          },
                        ),
                        Text("FIND HELP",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Column(

                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          child:  Image.asset('assets/bt2.png'),
                          onTap: (){
//                                        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
//                                          builder: (BuildContext context) => new Home(title: 'Bright Sky'),
//                                        ));
                          },
                        ),

                        Text("HOME",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        new InkWell(
                          child: Image.asset('assets/bt3.png'),
                          onTap: () {
                            //UrlLauncher.launch("tel://911");
                          },
                        ),
                        Text("CALL 999",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),


                  ],
                ),
//              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

I have put Container with Text just for testing purpose.
But above code gives me error that.

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 388 pixels on the bottom.
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
```

What i am doing wrong here? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter was not designed for UIs in which you just manually place which exact pixel you want your widgets to be. Instead, design your UI so that the composition itself determines where the widgets will end up being.

For example, you are using `Stack` and `Positioned` to try and float a container below another widget, when all you need to do is use an `Expanded` widget to make the first widget expand to fill all remaining space.

Also, you are using a `Container` with a fixed height inside a `SingleChildScrollView`, and the child of that is a `Column` with a bunch of fixed height `Container`s. This is the exact scenario that `ListView` was made for.

```
body: Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          // The list of containers
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              child:  Image.asset('assets/bt2.png'),
              onTap: (){},
            ),
            Text("HOME",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              child:  Image.asset('assets/bt3.png'),
              onTap: (){},
            ),
            Text("CALL 999",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

But to take this a step further, it looks like all you want to do is put some navigation buttons at the bottom of the screen. `Scaffold` already allows this with the `bottomNavigationBar` property. And when you do that, you no longer need a `Column` or `Expanded` to size your body as the only thing left to go there is the `ListView`.

```
Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      // The list of containers
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/bt2.png'),
        title: Text(
          "HOME",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Image.asset('assets/bt3.png'),
        title: Text(
          "CALL 999",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0,color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

There is power in composition. Do some research on the various widgets that Flutter offers. Check out the [Flutter Widget of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG) series on youtube. You'd be amazed at how many responsive and fluid UIs you can make without ever once manually specifying a fixed width and height of a widget.